# How to delete object from memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a very large dataset `dt`, which I split into train/test:

```
train_dt = dt().iloc[: dt.shape[0] * 8 // 10]

test_dt= dt().iloc[dt.shape[0] * 8 // 10:]
```

After I do that, I want to remove dt from memory, to keep more memory in ram. How to do that? I can do smth like`dt = 0`, but is there any better solution?

Comment: I think the best you can do is using python command 'del'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`del variable` can be used to delete a variable:

```py
train_dt = dt().iloc[: dt.shape[0] * 8 // 10]
test_dt= dt().iloc[dt.shape[0] * 8 // 10:]
del dt
```